# Looping through a nested list filter

Tags: python, list, filter, nested

Sorry if the title isnt correct, I am new at this and am self learning Python.  I have a current program that includes this...

```
    # Prompt function List
    whatIsYourNameL = ['my name is','i am called', 'you may call me']
    # Do this is if prompted
    def whatIsYourName()
        print(f'Hello {youName}')

    while True:

        if list(filter(lambda x: x in choice.lower(), changeYourNameList)):
            changeYourName()
        elif list(filter(lambda x: x in choice.lower(), whatIsYourNameList)):
            whatIsYourName()
        elif list(filter(lambda x: x in choice.lower(), whatIsMyNameList)):
            whatIsMyName()
```

Up until now I have used the same filter in a nested if - elif statement and changed the function names. I am now attempting to streamline by trying to do something like this...

```
     # Prompt function List
     whatIsYourNameL = ['my name is','i am called', 'you may call me']
     # Do this is if prompted
     def whatIsYourName()
        print(f'Hello {youName}')

     FunctList = ['changeYourName','whatIsYourName','whatIsMyName']
     c = choice.lower
     while True:    
    
        for funct in range(len(FunctList)):
            if list(filter(lambda x: x in c, f'{FunctList[funct]}L')):
                f'{FunctList[funct]}()'
```

Any ideas of how I can do this?

Comment: What is `c` in your code?

Comment: Can you store actual functions (i.e. remove the quotes) in `FuncList` definition? That would make the problem almost trivial

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me how your filter is supposed to work because I'm not sure what `c` is in your code, but this demonstrates the concept of building a list of functions and then looping over that list:

```
def changeYourName():
    print("change your name")

def whatIsYourName():
    print("what is your name?")

def whatIsMyName():
    print("what is my name?")

FunctList = [changeYourName, whatIsYourName, whatIsMyName]

for f in FunctList:
    f()
```

Note that the functions themselves go into the list, not strings that correspond to their names.  When you iterate over the contents of that list with `for f in FunctList`, each element (`f`) is a function that you can invoke, i.e. `f()`.

(edit)

Looking over your updated question, it looks like you're trying to associate a list of prefixes with each function, and then call the function that matches the prefix?  Here's how I might do it -- since you want to not only check for the match but presumably also strip the prefix (your code doesn't define a value for `youName` but based on context it seems like you'd want to extract it from that "my name is" string), it makes sense to me to put all of that logic into a single function so you don't have to handle the prefix in two different places:

```
from typing import Callable, Iterable


def strip_prefix_and_call(
    prefixes: Iterable[str],
    func: Callable[[str], None],
    arg: str
) -> None:
    """Given an arg that starts with one of a set of prefixes,
    strip the prefix from the arg and invoke the given func.
    Raises ValueError if none of the prefixes is in the arg."""
    try:
        prefix = [p for p in prefixes if arg.lower().startswith(p)][0]
        func(arg[len(prefix):])
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueError(f"{arg} does not start with any prefix in {prefixes}")


def my_name_is(name: str):
    print(f"Hello {name}")


def do_this_thing(command: str):
    print(f"I don't know how to {command}")


while True:
    choice = input("? ")

    for prefixes, func in [
        (['my name is ', 'i am called ', 'you may call me '], my_name_is),
        (['please ', 'i order you to ', 'would you kindly '], do_this_thing),
    ]:
        try:
            strip_prefix_and_call(prefixes, func, choice)
            break
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

```
? My name is Bob
Hello Bob
? Would you kindly assemble a martini
I don't know how to assemble a martini
```

Comment: "c" is a user written string such as "My name is David" or "They call me David". The original function looked up a list called "whatIsYourNameL" and in that list found a sub string of "c" that matched and so then ran the function "whatIsYourName()"

Comment: Where do the other functions come into it?  It'd help if we could see the code in its entirety and have some explanation of the overall objective; it's impossible to triangulate on the purpose when there's neither code nor documentation.  :)

Comment: In my original code, the filter was one of many each located inside a nested if else statement. So, if the filter didn't find a substring of c in its list it would go down to the next elif and see if a substring of c could was in its list and call that function instead

Comment: Sorry, nothing to do with what I am asking.  I have a function that strips the prefixes elsewhere. I just have code that is being repeated over and over again and the only thing that is changing is the names of the lists and the names of the def's. I am sure that this code can be put into a loop and change the names out from a list somehow but all my efforts have failed to date.

Comment: I think the principle of what you're trying to do should be illustrated in some part of the code I've given you, but if you need working code that exactly replicates what you're doing in your existing code, it's impossible to provide that without seeing your existing code.  Best of luck!